# For what values of $a$ does $\int_{0}^{1}(-\ln x)^adx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

For what values of $a$ does $\int_{0}^{1}(-\ln x)^adx$ converge? I have seen a duplicate of this question but the answer there, though very good and creative, isn't clear about negative values. When $a=0$ it is trivial. I actually did arrive at something for $a<0$: $\int_{0}^{1}(-\ln x)^a dx=[t=-\ln x, x=e^{-1}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-t}t^a)dt$. If $a<0$, then $t^a$ is bounded and $\int_{0}^{\omega}{e^{-t}}$ converges. By Abel, the integral converges. Is my proof admissible? Besides, is there a convenient way to treat the case "a>0"?

Comment: For $t\gg 0$ we have $0<e^{-t}t^a<e^{-t/2}$

Comment: So some negative $a$ values create problematic situations, as I understand. But some of them don't... How can I be sure?

Comment: See [history of the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By replacing $x$ with $e^{-t}$ we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}(-\log x)^{\alpha}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{\alpha}e^{-t}\,dt = \Gamma(\alpha+1) $$
so the integral is converging for any $\alpha>-1$.

Comment: I don't understand what $\Gamma$ stands for.

Comment: I see. It wasn't in the curriculum. Now everything makes sense. Thank you.